# Postgres cte with joins and where for multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

I’m curious about ctes in postgres db , I tried to use join inside but i got an error!

**My questions ?**

- Could i use where of multiple tables instead of inner join with a cte ?
- Is there another way to save table results if not cte suitable? I revised variables and they only suitable for one row ?

Comment: Generic question calls generic answer : I don't see any limitation within a cte compare to a standard query, which does not mean that cte is the universal solution for any complex query. Can you provide a concrete exemple where cte sounds not suitable for you ?

Comment: thanx for the comment @EdouardH. , I told that i can not use joins inside ctes .

Comment: I don't see any restriction for using joins inside cte, except for a recursive query which can call itself only once in the recursive part after the `UNION ALL` key word. You can check the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).Your error may be a syntax error ?

Comment: After some searching , I found views could improve ctes a bit

Comment: yes u are right joins can be used , my fault was that i used where before join .

Comment: You could add an answer @EdouardH.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used views, it is a better alternative. if somebody curious.